# Create revocation certificate - "No secret key"

Tags: gnupg

I have a GPG key, I can verify that I have the secret key and print out its content:

```
 $ gpg --list-secret-keys 
/home/user/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------
sec#  rsa2048 2019-07-11 [SC]
      9EEBCEAD0915834DFCE24B11A738D3C1E6BFA616
uid           [ultimate] My Name <my.email@email>
ssb   rsa2048 2019-07-11 [E]
```

I can print this out using

```
$ gpg --export-secret-keys -a
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
....
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

However, when I try to create a revocation certificate, I get:

```
$ gpg --gen-revoke 9EEBCEAD0915834DFCE24B11A738D3C1E6BFA616
gpg: secret keys "9EEBCEAD0915834DFCE24B11A738D3C1E6BFA616" not found: No secret key
```

Why would this be happening? Surely the system has access to a secret key, with which to generate the revocation cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can verify that I have the secret key

No you don't. The `#` means that the private part of the main key is missing. GnuPG still shows the whole entry only because you have private parts of some *subkeys*.

Each PGP key is actually a bundle of several independent RSA/DSA/EdDSA keys: one keypair for signing keys [C]; sometimes a separate keypair for signing messages [S]; and always a separate keypair for decrypting messages [E].

Because these keypairs have different purposes and require different levels of security, some people choose to deliberately export a partial PGP key into less-trusted machines – so if someone stole a laptop they'd be able to read old email but *wouldn't* be able to impersonate you using PGP.

Here your machine is also missing the private part of the [SC] key, meaning it can decrypt received email and files but cannot sign anything at all. And because editing or revoking your own key requires signing it with itself, that also becomes impossible without the [C] private key.

Comment: Thanks! Which secret key am I viewing with `--export-secret-keys -a` then..?

Comment: Exactly the same as in `--list-secret-keys`. Remember the part about how it's a _bundle_ of RSA keypairs (and PGP-specific metadata). So although you're missing the main RSA keypair, everything else is the same – the metadata (user IDs with name+email) is exported, the [E]ncryption subkey is exported, and the corresponding self-signatures are exported. You can use `pgpdump` to convert the exported key to text format (and notice that the topmost "Secret Key" packet is missing the private RSA parameters d/p/q/u, whereas "Secret Subkey" packets have still those parameters).

Comment: Does `--gen-revoke` always generate a revoc certificate linked to the primary key [C]? If i import the revoc cert does it mean the other subkeys also become revoked automatically because they were signed with the primary key [C] ?